# Problema al Incrementar un valor si lo actualiza en laravel

Tags: laravel

Necesito incrementar un valor si actualiza un dato, este es el código

```
DB::table('fac_det')->updateOrInsert(['id_producto' => $array_ids[$i], 'id_fac_enc' => $request->input('idfactura')])->increment(['cantidad' => $array_cantis[$i]]);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Pues me aparece este problema: "Call to a member function increment() on boolean" ya que intenté mezclar el updateOrInsert y el increment, ya que cuando quiero que me actualice el registro quiero que me incremente la cantidad ya que no puedo hacer un cantidad_vieja[i]+cantidad_nueva[i], ya que los sub indices no siempre van a coincidir

Comment: ¿Cuál? no dice nada ahí...

Comment: perdón, es que lo envíe sin nada, pero ya modifiqué el comentario

Comment: #Shaz viste el otro comentario?